# How to produce a Python dictionary from a C++ unordered map using SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, swig, typemaps, swig-typemap

I'm trying to wrap an unordered map in a python dictionary using swig:

```
// UsingAnUnorderedMap.h
#ifndef LEARNSWIG_USINGUNORDEREDMAP_H
#define LEARNSWIG_USINGUNORDEREDMAP_H

#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>


std::unordered_map<std::string, int> makeStringToIntMap(){
    return std::unordered_map<std::string, int>{
        {"first", 4},
        {"second", 5},
    };
}

#endif //LEARNSWIG_USINGUNORDEREDMAP_H
```

```
//UsingAnUnorderedMap.i
%module UsingUnorderedMap

%{
#include "UsingUnorderedMap.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
%}

%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_pair.i"
%include "std_unordered_map.i"

%template(StringToIntMap) std::unordered_map<std::string,int>;


%include "UsingUnorderedMap.h"
%typemap(out) StringToIntMap {
    PyDictObject* dict = PyDict_New($input);
    for (auto &item: StringToIntMap){
        PyDict_SetItem(dict, PyUnicode_FromString(item.first), item.second);
    }
    $result = dict;
}
```

```
# testUsingAnUnorderedMap.py
import sys

sys.path += [
    r"D:\LearnSwig\install-msvc\UsingUnorderedMap"
]

import UsingUnorderedMap

print(type(UsingUnorderedMap.makeStringToIntMap()))
```

This produces

```
<class 'UsingUnorderedMap.StringToIntMap'>
```

i.e. it just ignores the typemap. Technically the `StringToIntMap` behaves pretty much the same as a Python dict - at far as I can tell, but I think there's confort for Python users in Python dictionaries and so it would be better if this were a straight up dictionary. Does anybody have any pointers on how to achieve this?

For convenience, you can build this code using the following CMake code. Note that I build this using the command `-DSWIG_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/swig.exe`.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
set(Python_ROOT_DIR "C:/Miniconda3")
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)
        message("Python_EXECUTABLE ${Python_EXECUTABLE}")

find_package(SWIG 4.0.0 REQUIRED
        COMPONENTS python
        )

include(UseSWIG)

set_property(SOURCE UsingUnorderedMap.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)

swig_add_library(UsingUnorderedMap
        LANGUAGE python
        TYPE MODULE
        SOURCES UsingUnorderedMap.i UsingUnorderedMap)

set_target_properties(UsingUnorderedMap
        PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)

target_include_directories(UsingUnorderedMap PUBLIC
        ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        )
target_link_libraries(UsingUnorderedMap PUBLIC ${Python_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS UsingUnorderedMap DESTINATION UsingUnorderedMap)
install(FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/UsingUnorderedMap.py
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testUsingUnorderedMap.py
        DESTINATION UsingUnorderedMap)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes a small example showing conversion of `std::unordered_map` to a python dictionary

```
%module dictmap
%{
  #include "test.h"
%}

%typemap(out) std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> (PyObject* obj) %{
  obj = PyDict_New();
  for (const auto& n : $1) {
    PyObject* strA = PyUnicode_FromString(n.first.c_str());
    PyObject* strB = PyUnicode_FromString(n.second.c_str());
    PyDict_SetItem(obj, strA, strB);
    Py_XDECREF(strA);
    Py_XDECREF(strB);
  }
  $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, obj);
%}
%include "test.h"
```

Small inline function

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> makeStringMap() {
  return std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> {
    {"first", "hello"},
    {"second", "world"},
  };
}
```

I hope that you can see what you have made wrong. You are returning an empty dictionary created using an empty `$input`. I am not sure of whether you need to defined a `PyObject` argument, but I do this always in case it is needed together with another typemap.

Comment: It works, thank you! My swig noviceness shining through there - but yes, I see the mistake now. Could you elaborate a little on what you are doing with `SWIG_Python_AppendOutput`? It doesn't seems to be covered by the swig docs.

Comment: Aso it seems the second `#include "test.h"` isn't needed as it works okay without it

Comment: `SWIG_Python_AppendOutput` is a function to add stuff variables to output. You don't need it here, but I use it all the time. Often you have inout argument in C++ and in python you would like the results to go on the left. Using the funtion in question, you simply add an output to whatever was there beforehand

Comment: FYI, `PyDict_SetItem` doesn't steal references from the `PyUnicode` objects, so a `Py_DECREF` is needed on both of them.

Comment: You are right., the `PyUnicode_FromString` returns a new reference. I have added `Py_XDECREF` on the two `PyUnicode` objects.